# CSS Ribbon not appearing in safari

Tags: css, safari

I am new to using CSS, I usually only mess about with changing background colours etc. as I rarely have to create websites.

My Sister has asked me to make her a website for her University course, however when sending her over the website to view she can not see the Ribbon I have placed in the top right corner.

She is using Safari, I can not figure out how to get this sorted.

the CSS for the Ribbon is

```
    .ribbon {
  background-color: #3b5998;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* top right corner */
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 40px;
  /* 45 deg ccw rotation */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
.ribbon a {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font: bold 81.25% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* shadow */
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #444;
}

ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 201px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 201px;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 201px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 201px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

If anybody could guide me on what I have missed that would be great.

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: What version of Safari and what Operating System?

Comment: @ChristianHill The OS is OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
and the version of Safari is 9.0.2
The website in question is http://www.letchburnseries.co.uk/ and it should be appearing in the top right corner.

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine right now, but It's not just safari, it seems to be any browser in OS X. If use the web toolkit in Chrome, I don't even see any CSS for that element. Which style sheet is the CSS for .ribbon in? I just went through all the CSS files in your asset stack. I don't think the CSS you are providing above is included in the page.

Comment: `.ribbon` is nowhere to be found in CSS files. Plus you have a lot of errors, like using `<font>` thats deprecated.

Comment: Yes, it appears your CSS changes have not been uploaded to the server. Right now it says "Find us on Facebook" just below the menu on the left. There are no styles being applied to it.